# Is there a way to show value of the bar graph on hovering mouse over the individual bar in JFreeChart

Tags: tooltip, jfreechart

I have created a bar graph using the JFreeChart but is there a way to show the value of the bar graph on hovering the mouse over the individual bar.I am able to show the static value in the image using toolTipGenerator but it becomes quite messy if I have more data, so I was thinking to show the value of the individual bar graph on hovering mouse over the bar.
    Below is my code for generating the bar graph.

```
          CategoryItemLabelGenerator labelGenerator = new StandardCategoryItemLabelGenerator("{2}",
                    new DecimalFormat("0"));


            BarRenderer renderer= new BarRenderer();
            renderer.setBaseItemLabelGenerator(labelGenerator);

            JFreeChart barChart3D = ChartFactory.createBarChart3D("the graph name", "X-axis",
                              "Y-axis", dataset, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true, false);

            CategoryPlot plot = barChart3D.getCategoryPlot();
            plot.getDomainAxis().setCategoryLabelPositions(CategoryLabelPositions.UP_45);
            barChart3D.setAntiAlias(true);

            StandardCategoryToolTipGenerator toolTipGenerator=new StandardCategoryToolTipGenerator("{2}",
                    new DecimalFormat("0"));
            renderer.setBaseToolTipGenerator(toolTipGenerator);

            toolTipGenerator.generateToolTip(dataset, row, column)
            renderer.setBaseItemLabelsVisible(true);

            barChart3D.getCategoryPlot().setRenderer(renderer);
            XYLineAndShapeRenderer xylineandshaperenderer= new XYLineAndShapeRenderer();
            xylineandshaperenderer.setBaseToolTipGenerator((XYToolTipGenerator)new ItemGenerator());
```

Comment: It's not clear what's wrong. What do you mean by _messy_? How much is _more_?

Comment: @Catalina Island :- lets say  we create a bar graph for rainfall occurrence (days in X-axis and cm in Y axis) for say 60 days. If we show the value of rainfall occurrence (in cm) above the individual bar for all 60 days, then, since the individual bars are very close to each other(as 60 bars are to be adjusted in a single chart), the chart looks very clumsy with values above  each 60 bars. That's why I was thinking to show the value of the individual bar , if we hover mouse over a bar.

I hope, it makes more sense now.

Comment: What's not working how you want? Have you looked at `org.jfree.chart.demo.BarChartDemo1`?